# How to build a report that only lists the total number of people on multiple campaigns?

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I'm looking to create a report that only returns leads that are part of more than one campaign. Everyone else should be filtered out. Using Filters and Cross filters, I've been able to summarize it by their ID, but not filter them out. What is the best way to filter these contacts out? Is this even possible? Any insight is appreciated!

Edit: Since my question has been put on hold, let me try to detail out exactly what I am looking to do with this report:

- Report groups campaigns associated by Lead Full Name or Lead Id or Lead something else that is unique
- Report filters out any Leads with only one campaign (thus Leads with more than one campaign remain on the report)
- This report should be able to be used in a dashboard to provide a simple count of how many leads are associated with more than one campaign.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer but have you tried a report with the objects Contacts with Campaign Members? Why I think that route will work well is that it seems like you're basically looking for Contacts with multiple campaign member records. A Campaign Member record is a junction between Campaign and Contact. So if you want to see Contacts that have been attached to multiple campaigns you'll need to find Contacts that have multiple campaign member records.

Comment: @DanWooding I meant Lead, not Contact, so my mistake. Currently, I am using a cross filter of Leads with Campaign History. I can't find Campaign Members in the cross filter with Leads.

Comment: Okay it's the same concept. You may have to create a new report type. Setup -> Build -> Create -> Report Type -> New

Comment: What field is used to restrict it to showing only if the person has more than one campaign?

Comment: I've updated the text to include more specific details. If this could be reopened, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a custom report type "Leads With Campaign History" The main object being Leads and adding a related object "Campaign history". In the report summarize the groupings by Lead Name in my case I used Full Name. have another column for Campaign Name. When you run the report you'll see your Leads and the Campaigns they are associated with. Then create a report formula 'Number of Campaigns' grouping at the Lead Name. Then the formula is RowCount.

This gets you a report that looks like this:

[image]

Filter the report with Number of Campaigns greater than 1 and you'll get all Leads that have been associated to more than one Campaign and what Campaign they are associated to.

Comment: You can also click the `Hide Details` button.

Comment: I have it set up exactly as you have specified but I don't see the option to filter by the formula field that I've created.

Comment: On the customize screen there should be a filter button. Click that and then type in the name of your field.

Comment: Maybe I missed something during the setup of the custom report type, but when I click the add button next to filters and type in the column name, it says "No fields matched your search." Also, I noticed in your picture that your column doesn't have the formula Fx logo like mine does. Is this a custom field you built in the report or the leads category itself?

Comment: I apologize, after re looking at this you can't filter on the formula. There's an idea about it: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Jm0aAAC

I think you'll just have to visually see which ones have the multiple related Accounts.